# Axios interceptors and async loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I use vue.js with [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) library to send requests to my API. I want configurate it globaly and show Loading message, if request is too long.

I found, that I can use axios [interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) to configure axios globaly

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
  }, (error) => {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, (error) => {
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

To show notifications I use [f3oall/awesome-notifications](https://github.com/f3oall/awesome-notifications) (there are [version fot vue.js](https://github.com/f3oall/vue-awesome-notifications)); So I try to do something like this

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    this.$awn.info("Try to send request");
    return config;
}, (error) => axios_error(error));

axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    this.$awn.success("Success!");
    return response.data;
}, (error) => axios_error(error));

function axios_error(error) {
    //this.$awn.alert("Request error"); // not works - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '$awn' of undefined

    return Promise.reject(error);
}
```

But I have next problems:

**First.** I don't want to show success messages using `sucess` method. I want to use `asyncBlock()` method - it shows loader and blocks the screen untill promise will be completed, then run a callback or show new toast.

```
asyncBlock(promise, onResolve, onReject, html)
```

But how can I use it inside `interceptors.request` and `interceptors.response`?

**Second.** In `axios_error()` I can't use `this`. As result `this.$awn.alert("Request error");` not works. How can I fix this?

---

I just want globaly configure next behavior: if I send requst and it's duration more than 500ms - show asyncBlock dots (fullwindow loading message). If an error occurred during the request, show error message - `this.$awn.alert("Request error")`. If no errors - don't show any messages.

How can I do this? Any other variants?

Answer (score 0):

**First.** You can exploit the `config` object that is accessible in both request and response interceptors:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    // Create a promise to pass to asyncBlock
    config.loadingScreenPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        config.resolveLoadingScreenPromise = resolve;
        config.rejectLoadingScreenPromise = reject;
    });
    this.$awn.asyncBlock(config.loadingScreenPromise, //... other params)

    return config;
}, (error) => axios_error(error));

axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
    // resolve loading screen promise
    response.config.resolveLoadingScreenPromise()

    return response.data;
}, (error) => {
    // reject loading screen promise
    error.config.rejectLoadingScreenPromise(error)
    axios_error(error)
});
```

**Second.** Either call `this.$awn.alert()` directly from error interceptor lambda function(to access Vue component's `this`) or pass `this.$awn` to `axios_error` function explicitly.